Weird topology shading in viewport
I retopologized my sculpt and there's this weird dismorphing even though my topology looks complete fine.



I don't see any problems in the retopology which makes me wonder how to fix this

Could you share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Hello, maybe inverted normals, or inner faces, or overlapping vertices?

@HarryMcKenzie i think my file is too big to share it. Is there another way?

@moonboots Oh this worked! I just had to recalculate the normals to outside. Thank you so much

Recalculate the normals in Edit mode (ShiftN)
